# Variation von einerseits-andererseits

Tags: idiom, style

Ist "einerseits - andererseits" gänzlich idiomatisch, oder kann man  einen Satz wie

> Einerseits freute er sich über das Geschenk, andererseits wusste er wenig damit anzufangen.

auch beispielsweise zu

> Zwar freute er sich über das Geschenk, andererseits wusste er wenig damit anzufangen.

oder

> Einerseits freute er sich über das Geschenk, aber dennoch wusste er wenig damit anzufangen.

variieren? Ist das stilistisch schlecht, verwirrend, oder gar Schlimmeres?

Comment: Das ist wohl eher Ansichtsache.

Comment: Jeder der Sätze ist möglich, ob man sie gut findet oder nicht, ist Meinung / Ansichtssache. Deshalb vtc.

Comment: Es verändert die Bedeutung, die Nuancen sind anders. Natürlich kannst du variieren, drückst dann aber eben nicht völlig identisch dasselbe aus.

Comment: Mag sein, dass es Ansichtssache ist, darum hier meine Ansicht: Ich finde die Beispiele bis auf eine Kleinigkeit unauffällig. Die Kleinigkeit wäre das "aber dennoch", für mich eine Doppelung - auch darüber werden die Ansichten auseinandergehen. Die Frage ist, ob ein Satzanfang mit 'einerseits' den Erwartungsdruck erzeugt, dass es mit einem passgenauen 'andererseits-Satz' weitergeführt und abgeschlossen werden möge. Für 'einerseits' ist das bei mir nicht so, anders als bei 'zum einen', da würde ich mehr oder weniger unbedingt das 'zum anderen' erwarten.

Comment: @MelissaLoos ich fände es gut, wenn Du Deinen Kommentar zu einer Antwort erweitern würdest: inwiefern ändert sich die Bedeutung denn?

Comment: Es ist nur eine persönliche Meinung, ich müsste mir da noch tiefergehend Gedanken machen. In Beispiel drei liest sich für mich der Satz eher so, als würde dem Geschenk der Wert durch den zweiten Satzteil abgesprochen. Das liest sich in Beispiel eins wesentlich positiver, da ist das so 50:50, bei Beispiel 3 würde ich das eher so 20:80 schätzen und bei Beispiel 2... 35:65? Schwer in Worte zu fassen, aber ich finde, dass die Wortwahl hier viel Unterton mit rein bringt. "Aber dennoch" ist da ein gutes Beispiel, das negiert für mich stark das vorhergesagte.

Comment: Ja, es ist stilistisch schlecht. Jeder *darf* so reden oder schreiben, aber wenn's ein Zeitungsredakteur oder sonstiger Sprachprofi zu Gesicht bekommt, wird er es redigieren, so wie er auch Metaphernbrüche redigieren wird. (Gewisse Ausnahmen auf hohem Niveau der Sprachbeherrschung sind möglich, siehe die Antwort unten von mtwde.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schaut man sich den DWDS-Korpus für die Wörter [einerseits](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=kern;q=einerseits) und [andererseits](https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=kern;q=%7Bandererseits,andrerseits,anderseits%7D) an wird man sehen, dass die mehr als überwiegende Mehrheit der Beispiele beide Wörter benutzt (vor allem einerseits scheint kaum ohne seinen Gegenpart auszukommen). Es gibt allerdings auch Beispielsätze wie

> Einerseits ärgert sich Hannelore über mich, aber dann macht sie einen Umschwenker, weil sie eben nicht nur meckern will, und schreibt noch »Schlaf gut«.
>
> Dem Ganzen entströmte ein heftiger Geruch, der mir einerseits vertraut, in seiner Heftigkeit dann allerdings auch wieder fremd war.
>
> Pterodaktylen besitzen zwar einige Eigenschaften von Vögeln, wie etwa zur aerodynamischen Fortbewegung taugliche Schwingen und Hornschnäbel, andererseits legen sie keine Eier und benehmen sich auch ansonsten sehr vogelunspezifisch.
>
> Der Typ tut mir ziemlich leid, andererseits ärgert es mich, daß ich unter Streß packen muß und dann wieder etwas passiert, was mein sensibles Gemüt nicht in einer Sekunde verarbeiten kann.

Auf der [Duden-Homepage](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/einerseits-andererseits) findet man zusätzlichen folgenden Abschnitt

> Die mehrgliedrige Konjunktion einerseits – andererseits kann gleichrangige Sätze miteinander verbinden, die einen inhaltlichen Gegensatz ausdrücken. [...] Beide Teile der Konjunktion können auch in den jeweiligen Satz eingebunden sein: [...] Vor andererseits bzw. vor dem mit andererseits ergänzten Satz steht grundsätzlich ein Komma. Das Wort einerseits kann bei solchen Satzverbindungen fehlen, auch in diesem Fall muss vor andererseits ein Komma gesetzt werden. Du hast sicher recht mit deiner Einschätzung, andererseits solltest du bedenken, wie hart die Situation für ihn sein muss.
>
> Das Wort andererseits kann auch in einen eigenständigen zweiten Satz einbezogen sein: Er ist sicher ziemlich überheblich. Es lässt sich aber andererseits nicht leugnen, dass er sehr hilfsbereit ist.

Demnach wäre zumindest

> Zwar freute er sich über das Geschenk, andererseits wusste er wenig damit anzufangen.

akzeptabel.

Comment: Danke! Nach dieser Rückmeldung werde ich zumindest die Varainte "Einerseits, sonstwas" dringend vermeiden